# Arrow buttons or best recommendation on UI for traversing records like VCR buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I trying add arrow buttons to my app. I dont know how to show arrows on button ?
http://www.bestandroidappsreview.com/2010/09/build-vocabulary-sat-gre-buddy-android-app.html

otherwise , I want some suggestion on what would a good interface for traversing of records for next and previous ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an Arrow on button, You need to have an Images for the Arrow. Usually when you use Image button, it keeps the background of the button as normal button so you can not have a look and feel like the one you have.
The Best option is use ImageView instead of Button or ImageButton and Use Arrow Images to show Arrows.